# Water based stain and polyester. Causing streaks and blotches in the stain blotches

Tags: wooden-furniture

Why does the w/b polyurathane loosen the stain and make it move and create blotches in the stain. I am using varathane stain and polyurethane

Comment: This question could use some photos demonstrating the problem, and/or a better description of the problem. It's hard to visualize what you're asking about.

Comment: How much time between the staining and the polyurethane?

Comment: I might suggest perusing the "Finishing" tag at the [woodworking.se] sister site. _Loads_ of good info there on how to finish, why finishing has gone wrong, and how to fix it when it does. In the meantime, _please_ [edit] your question to provide more details, like the _exact_ name of the finishes in question. There are a lot of different products produced by Varathane

Comment: is the stain also water-based? If so, there ya go...

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered your problem on occasion. It usually always stems from impatience (mine), when I don't allow enough time between staining and clear coat. There are a number of factors that effect the stains drying time. Temp., humidity, type of stain and wood, method of application.
Give the stain more time to cure. Just dry to a touch may not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear, but I think you are saying that you apply water based stain, get a stain you are happy with, and then apply water-based polyurethane over it and it screws up the stain.

So, you need either to use an oil-based stain and water-based poly, or water based stain and oil-based poly, or you need to apply a barrier coat between the two layers of water-based finish, as the stain is evidently not curing to insolubility (though it's possible that simply **letting the stain cure for several days to a week** would solve that - worth a test. Use some scrap wood and try that.)

Since you are using Varathane stain and Varathane poly, you could also try calling (800) 901-0411 (if in the USA) Or look for other contact methods and local support numbers here: https://rustoleumsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/360005959712-Help-and-Support

Shellac is one classic approach to a **barrier or seal coat**. "Workable fixative" from an art supply store is another. One coat of oil-based poly followed by the rest in water based would also work.